# fstab logs out the swap-related configuration, but swap is still turned on after the machine restarts

Tags: linux, swap

fstab logs out the swap-related configuration, but swap is still turned on after the machine restarts.

I checked the kernel log about swap

[    0.646690] Spectre V1 : Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
[    3.082605] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[    5.371570] systemd[1]: Activating swap Swap Partition...
[    5.397753] Adding 67108860k swap on /dev/nvme0n1p3.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:67108860k SSFS
[    5.404070] systemd[1]: Activated swap Swap Partition.